# Earliest date after current date without associated record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a Rails model `DailyAssignment` with a date column, and would like to find the first date after today which does not have a `DailyAssignment` associated with it.

For instance, if I have an instance today, no instance tomorrow, and an instance the day after tomorrow, this method should return tomorrow.

If I were to do this in Ruby, it would be something like:

```
(Date.today..1.year.since.to_date).find do |date|
  DailyAssignment.where(date: date).empty?
end
```

This is medium okay since it will terminate the iteration once it finds a record, but has two issues:

1. Iterating through a collection in Ruby is slow.
2. Barring some sort of `while` construct, I need to specify an 'end' date.

Is there a nice, efficient way to do this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: It's been a while since my postgres days, but if you could outer join against a table of dates, couldn't you select the minimum date where date_assignment_id is null and date > today?

Obviously this requires access to some table of dates which I'm not sure if there's a more idiomatic sql way of doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, you should use a custom query to search through your database (these kind of searches are a lot faster within the DB).

If you search for a date within a time range, you can use the
[`generate_series(timestamp, timestamp, interval)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) function:

```
select    s
from      generate_series(?, ? + interval '1 year'), interval '1 day') s
left join daily_assignment on s = "date"
where     "date" is null
limit     1
```

If you have no real upper bound, you can use a self-join to get the next *free* date:

```
select coalesce(
  (select    c."date" + interval '1 day'
   from      daily_assignment c
   left join daily_assignment n on n."date" = c."date" + interval '1 day'
   where     c."date" > ? - interval '1 day'
   and       n."date" is null
   order by  c."date"
   limit     1),
  ? + interval '1 day'
)
```

**?** marks mean the parameter of today (you *may* need casts, depending on your input); you could use `now()` instead, if you prefer.

**P.S.**: please, do not use `date` as a column name, it is a reserved word in SQL, and tells nothing about the column itself. Instead, you can use names like `created_at`, `updated_at`, `happens_at`, etc. or even `at_date`.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I am looking for. Rails can execute arbitrary SQL as an argument of `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`, so this is perfect.

Comment: @user2272439 i left out the `order by` clause from my unbound (second) query, see the updated -- you may not need the outer select in the second  one, it only makes sure you always get the next free date, but you can simulate it in ruby easily: if you get no results from the inner query, that means *tomorrow* is the next free date.

Answer (score 0):

What I propose is to do 1 select query between dates, then loop your results and compare them with your selected results.

```
# select all dailyassignments
results = DailyAssignment.where("date >= from_date AND date <= to_date")

not_found_dates = []

(Date.today..1.year.since).find do |date|
  found_assignment = results.detect {|instance| instance.date == date }
  not_found_dates << date if found_assignment.nil?
end
```

Comment: It's a definite improvement on speed, just by moving the DB call up the stack. Since find and detect are functionally identical here, I would write this as `(Date.today..1.year.since.to_date).find{|date| results.find{|instance| instance.date == date}.nil?}`. However I still benchmark this at around 0.1 s. I'd like a PostgresQL solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way:

```
def first_date_without_assignment
  assignments = DailyAssignment.select('date').where('date > ?', Date.today)
  return Date.tomorrow if assignments.empty?

  assignment_dates = assignments.map(&:date)
  date_range = (Date.tomorrow..(assignment_dates.last.advance(days: 1)).to_a

  (date_range - assignment_dates).first
end
```

I didn't test it so I could mistype something, but it could work. I also find this, it should work on postgres http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4F96EC90.6070600@encs.concordia.ca but it could be quite hard to write in rails or at least bad looking.

Comment: A similar strategy, but still does the actual processing in Ruby. I'll take a look at your link.

Comment: This takes several seconds for a large enough collection of dates. Also, the penultimate line is missing a `)` and the first line needs an `order(:date)` on the end.

Comment: Yes it, can take several seconds for a large enough collection of dates. As I said, I didn't test it, but there is no problem with end date. I absolutely agree the database solution would be much better. This solution is only to show other way, how you can think about it :)

Comment: Just for information: What is a large enough collection?